# HTTPS not working on port 5000 of my domain (ex. domainexample.com:5000)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, http, amazon-ec2, https

I added SSL on my domain using lets encrypt and connected it to my EC2 instance. I can access my domain with an https. But when i try to access it with a port (for example: mydomain.com:5000), https is not working. I need port 5000 because thats where my node app listens to. How do i solve this? Accesing with http seemed to work but when it tried with https, it just gives me a site cant be reached page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need one of the following:

- A web server running on EC2 running HTTPS, this would proxy to port 5000.
- An application load balancer with a listener of HTTPS, that forwards to a target group on port 5000

Comment: i already have a web server running on EC2 with https. How do i setup the other ones?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-application-load-balancer.html. Just set target port as 5000 :)